# flutter Fetch json data by category

Tags: json, laravel, flutter, dart, rest

I am currently developing an ecommerce app. I use a ListView.builder to display data but I don't know how to fetch the products according to the selected category.

Here is the model of the list of categories

```
    class Category {
  final int id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String slug;
  

  Category({this.id, this.name, this.image, this.slug,});

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      image: json['image'].toString(),
      slug: json['slug'],
      
    );
  }
}

class Produit {
  
  String productName;
  String productImage;
  int productPrice;
  String description;
  int rating;
  int numberOfRating;
  int category;

  Produit(
      {this.productName,
      this.productImage,
      this.productPrice,
      this.description,
      this.rating,
      this.numberOfRating,
      this.category});

  factory Produit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Produit(
      productName: json['name'],
      productImage: json["image"],
      productPrice: json["prix"],
      description: json["description"].toString(),
      rating: json["rating"],
      numberOfRating: json["numberOfRating"],
      category: json["category"]
    );
  }
}
```

This is the widget that displays the list of products by category.

```
class ProduitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProduitPage({
    Key key,
    this.categoryId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  int categoryId;

  @override
  _ProduitPageState createState() => _ProduitPageState();
}

class _ProduitPageState extends State<ProduitPage> {
  List<Produit> _produits = List<Produit>();

  

  Future<List<Produit>> fetchProduits() async {
    //var url = 'http://192.168.8.100:8000/api/produits';
    var url = apilink + prod_url;
    final response = await http.get(url);
    var produits = List<Produit>();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var produitsJson = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var produitJson in produitsJson) {
        produits.add(Produit.fromJson(produitJson));
      }
      return produits;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Impossible de charger les données.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchProduits().then((value) {
      _produits.addAll(value);
    });
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Restaurant'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                new SearchWidget()));
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 30,
                ),
                CartIconWithBadge(),
              ]),
          body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _produits.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return Container(
                child: (_produits[i].category == categoryId),
              );
            },
          ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to display data by selected category. Please I really need your help. thanks!!

Comment: what are using ,firebase ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :), The question your have put forward is has a very large scope, so it is difficult to answer your question without making assumptions about the application. To get a helpful answer I would suggest updating your question with your widget code as well. Also make it clear if you want to do run this function client slide or server side.

Comment: @AmanVerma I'm using laravel RESTful api with jwt

Comment: @RohanThacker I add the widget code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for updating your question

While there are many ways you can achieve your desired result, I have mentioned one solution below.

Since you have a list of products available in the widget, you can use the `List.where` method to filter the product list by category and display the results of that function in your widget

[More details and sample code available on](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Iterable/where.html)

**Note**: Replace calling the `API` function in the build method directly and replace it with the `FutureBuilder` widget. The code sample above will make a call to the `API` on each build.
More details and sample code available on [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)